# Updating multiple model attributes incrementally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've recently started looking into Ruby on Rails, and I've set up a basic system to scan an parse and XML datasource, storing the elements in a MySQL database.

I'm intending to run the script as a rake task at set intervals to detect data changes, I'm scanning data from multiple regions and currently have two database tables set up, `Product` and `Product Info`.

`Product` stores data that's persistent across all regions, data which isn't persistent such as name and price are stored in the `ProductInfo` table along with the region locale.

In order to detect changes I have defined `touch: true` in the `ProductInfoController` to ensure that the `Product`'s `updated_at` column is changed if the `ProductInfo` is changed during the XML data parsing.

To update the values I am using `find_or_initialize_by` to catch any existing records, and then I am calling `update`, passing in **all** the attributes from the XML datasource. If none of the attributes change the `updated_at` column for the record is not altered on the `ProductInfo` table, however it is still altered in the `Product` table.

```
product = Product.find_or_initialize_by(guid: xml.guid)
product.update(category: xml.category)

product_info = ProductInfo.find_or_initialize_by(product_id: product.id, locale: xml.locale)
product_info.update(name: xml.name, price: xml.price)
```

So the issue is that the touch is called whenever save is called on the model, this occurs in the update call. Is there an alternate call I could use, or a better way to set these attributes? Or, is there a better way to update the attributes incrementally?

Comment: Check this - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

Here you can check if any value has changed, then only fire update query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `.update()` I have changed the code to use `.update_attributes`, this allows for me to check if the object has changed using `.has_changed?`, as suggested by @icicle. I can then perform appropriate actions prior to committing the changes with `.save`.